# How can I get a bone for a bone shiv without getting lucky with a drop?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

Alpha 13 changed the game drastically and you now need a bone shiv or a hunting knife or a machete to gut animals. But you need bones from animals or as a drop from Zeds to actually get a bone shiv, which seems like a catch 22 problem.

How can I get a bone without relying on a drop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my experience, the normal club is the best way to harvest an animals prior to having the bone shiv. It will yield little meat, no hides, but 1-5 Bones if you finish harvesting the animal. From there, craft a bone shiv and you are good to go to harvest your next animal. Keep the bones around since you cannot repair your bone shiv.

Answer (score 3):

In A15, you can use a stone axe to swing at a corpse. Once you've collected all of the meat from it and it degrades to its final form, it will start yielding bones.

In general, the axe is better for harvesting meat than the club. The bone shiv is better than the axe, and the hunting knife is best once you can craft it.

Answer (score 0):

I've only played a dozen hours or so, but after a while, I discovered that there's very often a bone hanging out on a zombie's corpse. It doesn't show up when you're looting, but it's just sitting there after you loot and the corpse is a mess. Or sometimes it shows up after I whack the corpse with my axe and it turns into a pile of guts -- with a bone and some rotted meat sitting around.

Because of this, in my still limited experience, animals have been way more rare than bones for shivs.